# Can I successfully compile a C++ program using wxWidgets with GCC12 or 13?

Tags: gcc, wxwidgets

I am insecure about the given compiler version with wxWidgets. I downloaded
wxWidgets-3.2.3-headers.7z
wxMSW-3.2.3_gcc810_x64_Dev.7z
wxMSW-3.2.3_gcc810_x64_ReleaseDLL.zip
and I want to create a program using wxWidgets with a GCC 12 or even the latest GCC 13.
Will that work?
What other setup is preferred?

Comment: I well maintained toolkit should work with actual compilers. If not, fill a bug report. No idea what are current versions of wxwidgets libs are, but if not fully outdated, I should work. Maybe you get some warnings which are not visible with older compilers. But why you ask? Simply type make!

Comment: @Martin_from_K, why do you not want to build the library yourself? It's easy. Download the source code, unpack it, go to wxWidgets\build\msw and type `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=Debug`. Then you will be absolutely sure it will be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxWidgets 3.2.3 binaries compiled with MSYS2 MinGW 12.2.0 and 13.2.0 are also available, so you should use those if you use one of these compilers. Otherwise, you can easily compile the library yourself.